Kotlin Barcode Script to Cut the Code (AndroidStudio)
I would like to have a function which, when I scan a barcode and the digits
the digits “0944” appear the following things are cut off:
018187109448439015513329272
so that only “09448439015513” remains. the digits:
01818710
and
329272
are never the same, so it is best to cut them off using the digits.
I currently have the following script which unfortunately does not work properly.
    private fun processBarcode(barcode: String): String {
        val index = barcode.indexOf(“0944”)
        return if (index != -1 && barcode.length >= index + 14) {
            val start = index - 7
            val end = index + 10
            if (start >= 0 && end + 6 <= barcode.length) {
                val part1 = barcode.substring(start + 7, end)
                val part2 = barcode.substring(end, end + 6)
                part1 + part2
            } else {
                barcode
            }
        } else {
            barcode
        }
    }

What am I doing wrong? I can't find the error.
I have already tried many different approaches. Unfortunately, so far always without success.

Since you didn't accept your own answer I assume you want to see other solutions as well. In that case you have to specify your problem more clearly How is the part that remains is defined? Is it a given character length? Also, what should happen when 0944 occurs multiple times (especially when it occurs in the first part that should be removed); what should happen when it never occurs? Are the parts to be removed always fixed in lenght or are the of a variable length? Please [edit] your question to add the missing information and provide sample input and expected output for each case.

okay, i solved it by myself.. sorry
private fun processBarcode(barcode: String): String {
        val pattern = "0944"
        val index = barcode.indexOf(pattern)
        return if (index != -1 && barcode.length >= index + 14) {
            val relevantPart = barcode.substring(index - 7, index + 14 + 6)
            relevantPart.substring(7, 21) // Extrahiere die relevanten 14 Zeichen
        } else {
            barcode
        }
    }


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
